# Json file needs to convert to Objects before inserting to mysqlite?

Tags: json

I am making an Android apps and I have a big json file and I like to store it in mysqlite.

Should I convert the json file to objects before inserting into mysqlite?

thanks.

Comment: Did you mean SQLite? SQLite is a simple database that uses SQL as primary language. You'll have to insert the data using SQL or you could use MongoDB (a Object-Oriented Database).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Before I use sql to store the data, do I need to convert the json file into object? (deserialization)

Comment: How else are you going to access your data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I like to put the contents in sqlite and I have a json file.  Before I do that, do I need to deserialized?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you were able to convert it to JSON object. After that You should convert the JSON object to a String then save the string as VARCHAR in the DB